# Where did /usr/bin/git come from?

Tags: macos, git

I have a small problem. At some point I used git but I don't remember if it was installed by default on Lion.

Here is the version and path of git:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

I also have a newer git in /usr/local/git

I would like to use the newer version but I don't know if by removing the old one (/usr/bin has precedence in the path variable) I'll break something.

What is the proper way to resolve this conflict?

Comment: git is installed by Xcode. I can't tell you if it'll break anything, though. In your shoes, I'd rename it in case I need to put it back later.

Comment: ah ok..Well what I'll do is just rename the new installt o git2 or something and use it like that.

Comment: I meant rename the old one, rather than removing it. That way if you DO have problems you can just rename it back.

Comment: @StevenFisher you should make that an answer. :)

Comment: OK. I was hoping someone would have a real answer that didn't have an "I don't know!" in it. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

git is installed by Xcode. I doubt you'll have any problems if you replace it, but I can't give you a definitive answer to that…

1. What I'd do is rename the old `/usr/bin/git` to `git_old`, then rely on your path to select the new one.
2. **If that doesn't work**, move the new one to `/usr/bin`. I doubt Xcode is picky about which version of git it's using.
3. **If that still doesn't work**, move `git_old` back to `/usr/bin/git` and use either a direct path, rename, or alias for your new one.

I doubt you'll have to go past #1 above, though. That should be enough.

Edit: I read your original post backwards. The first thing you should do is make sure your path includes the new git directory BEFORE the directory that contains the old git.

Comment: 3 alternatives: confirming that the first one worked well.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to go hacking the other version out unless you are really tight for space. Edit your .bash_profile and make sure that /usr/local/bin occurs in front of /usr/bin in your PATH variable

Personally I prefer to adopt a scheme with tool paths defined and the path built from these e.g.

```
GIT_HOME=/usr/local

PATH=${GIT_HOME}/bin:${PATH};export PATH
MANPATH=${GIT_HOME}/share/man:${MANPATH};export MANPATH
```

This means that anything that searches for tools using the PATH will find your version of git, and anything that "really must" have the /usr/bin version will most likely have that path hard wired in and can still find it

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem: an old version of Git that was the Xcode version. I've tried to install a new version of Git from http://git-scm.com/ and updated the `bash_profile` with

```
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Then reload your bash and try `git --version`

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

On my system (10.7.3, Xcode 4.3.2) Xcode's `git` is not installed in `/usr/bin/git`.  All of Xcode 4 (like all apps from the App Store, I think) is in its .app bundle.  Specifically, its git is at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git`.

I use git (via Xcode) all the time, and I have no `/usr/bin/git` here at all.  So it's not part of the default Lion install, either, or at least, not at that location.

FWIW, the git in the Xcode.app bundle has a `--version` that reads:

> git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26)

so I bet your `/usr/bin/git` is your own installation, and updating it can't hurt anything.

Alternatively, you could install Xcode (it's free!), and put `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/` in your $PATH, but that's overkill if you only want git.

Comment: I also have xcode, so I have three versions of git currently installed... nice find!

Comment: if you don't have `/usr/bin/git`, you probably didn't install the Xcode "Command Line Tools". see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9329243/152142

Answer (score 1):

Ken is correct in that git was only available through the Xcode.app path.
When I installed Mountain Lion (10.8), suddenly I had git in /usr/bin/git, so it was a Mountain Lion addition as far as I can tell...

Although...I have installed quite a few things since and am not entirely sure it wasn't a dependency for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know, I think I haven't installed git or XCode for the momment but after install homebrew and run `brew doctor` it says:

```
$ brew doctor
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

So why? I just installed Command Line Tools for XCode (mountain Lion) and I think this one is the one who installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many things.  Finally I was able to get brew's version of git to run instead of Xcode's by simply deleting Xcode's additional tools folder:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`